# Non-uniform axis of imagesc() in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, time-series

**Question:** is it possible to illustrate an image on non-uniform axis?

**Details:**

I need to illustrate a multidimensional timeseries as an image. But the time grid of this timeseries is very non-uniform. Here is an example:

```
m = 10;
n = 3;
t = sort(rand(m, 1));  % non-uniform time
values = randn(m, n);  % some random values
```

The `figure, plot(t, values);` handles it well.

But `imagesc()` converts `t` into uniform time between `t(1)` and `t(end)` according to documentation:

> imagesc(x,y,C) displays C as an image and specifies the bounds of the
>   x- and y-axis with vectors x and y.

Therefore, the command:

```
figure, imagesc(t, 1 : n, values'); colorbar;
```

illustrates the image on uniform time grid.

[image]
[image]

**Edit:** It's possible to re-sample the timeseries with higher uniform resolution. But my timeseries is already very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Try using `surface` for non-uniform spacing.

First, create a 3D xyz surface of the same size as your input data:

```
m = 10;
n = 3;
t = sort(rand(m, 1));  % non-uniform time
values = randn(m, n);  % some random values
x = repmat(t,1,n);
y = repmat(1:n,m,1);
z = zeros(size(y));
```

Then, colormap your values.  There is a nice tool posted to the mathworks file exchange, [real2rgb](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23342-real2rgb-colormaps), that can do this for you:

```
cdata = real2rgb(values);  % Where size(cdata) = [m n 3]
```

Lastly, plot the surface. You can even get fancy and set the transparency.

```
surface(x,y,z,cdata,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','texturemap',...
  'CDataMapping','direct');
alpha(0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, it looks interesting. I will check when i'm near PC.

Comment: However this pcolor or surface method, remove one column and one row at the edge!

Answer (score 5):

There is **pcolor** function in MATLAB. This function does exactly what you're asking.

```
m = 10;
n = 3;
t = sort(rand(m, 1));  % non-uniform time
values = randn(m, n);  % some random values
figure
plot(t, values);
figure
pcolor(t, 1 : n, values'); 
colorbar;
```

Comment: However this pcolor or surface method, remove one column and one row at the edge!

Answer (score 4):

try [uimagesc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11368-uimage-uimagesc) from the file exchange.

[image]

Comment: Thanks natan. It works well, but not applicable for my 2GB matrix (timeseries). At some point it resamples the data with higher resolution. For instance, 10 time points of `t` became 269 points.

Comment: If you have a 2GB matrix, isn't it more logical to re-sample it to something reasonable (using imresize or similar)? A 1920x1200x24 bit screen can only show about 10MB of information, what good is it to give it a 2GB matrix?

Comment: It's correct, but I need to see actual time scale when zoom-in. Suppose, the figure illustrates 24 hours of some data, and I need to see what happens during specific 1 second. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at 'jplot' at matlab central. Which dynamically resamples date depending on zoom level